# How to remove the property values in application.properties and set them dynamically in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

My application.properties file looks like this

```
#jwt
app.jwt.secret=RandomSecretKey
#1 day
app.jwt.expiration-in-ms=86400000
app.jwt.token.prefix=Bearer
app.jwt.header.string=Authorization

support.email=admin@xyz.co
spring.mail.host=smtpout.asia.secureserver.net
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.username=admin@xyz.co
spring.mail.password=******
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtps.timeout=8000
```

I want to remove them from this file and set them by retrieving the values from database using JPA repositories. How to do this?

Comment: There are different ways to achieve this. But what i don't understand from your question is you need to override JPA specific properties also? eg: spring.jpa.database-platform? Why do you need to do this. Why can't you pass this arguments via environment variables at the time of deployment?

Comment: @JustinMathew I didn't notice that, edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [consul.io](https://www.consul.io/) to store and get your properties.

So if you use consul it's possible update the properties values at runtime using the annotation `@RefreshScope`

Example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-consul